# Javascript regex for number check and maximum length of 3 and does not start with 0

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I am trying to find a regular expression, that does the following

> 1) checks number
>
> 2) Allows max length of 3
>
> 3) Does not start with 0

I have the following regex which works fine

`^[0-9]{1,3}$`

Above regular expression allows only numbers that have maximum 3 digits but I am not sure how to prevent 0 in the beginning.

code

```
var numericRegex = new RegExp("^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$");
numericRegex.test(123) //false
```

Let me know what I am missing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$
```

or:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

In node.js it can be used like this:

```
> "123".match(/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$/)
[ '123', index: 0, input: '123' ]
> "023".match(/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$/)
null
> "123".match(/^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$/)
[ '123', index: 0, input: '123' ]
> "023".match(/^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$/)
null
```

And the other answer is also fine:

```
> "123".match(/^(?!0)\d{1,3}$/)
[ '123', index: 0, input: '123' ]
> "023".match(/^(?!0)\d{1,3}$/)
null
```

Comment: I have tried your second regex,since the first one looks more verbose
the second one allows 012 which is what I am trying to avoid..

Comment: the first one does not allow me to enter '123' :|

Comment: @stackoverman It should: `/^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$/.test('123') // true`

Comment: I am editing my question with code..let me know what is wrong

Comment: I am tring again to see if i missed anything

Comment: Perhaps you need quotes around the 123

Comment: it is working with quotes around 123
but how to make it work without quotes

Comment: Regexes work on strings, not numbers. You can convert a number to a string with String(123).

Comment: @AdrianMay I dont understand how my previous regex worked with number. But the regex in your answer does not. Anyways it is working now. Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 2):

Or could be done with

```
^(?!0)\d{1,3}$
```

Comment: not sure if am missing anything
it does not allow me to enter 123

Answer (score 0):

Shortest regex is should be

```
^[1-9]{1}\d{2}$
```